# How To Apply Multiple Data Validation In One Cell In Excel Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, data-validation

I want to apply 2 conditions on a range of cells.

The first one is each cell takes value from a drop down list. I implemented this by Data Validation dialog box, selecting List option and typing the name of the list of possible values I created.

Secondly, I want each cell to be able to take these values only if another cell is empty. I can implement this by Data Validation dialog box, selecting Custom option and typing the formula: =NOT(ISBLANK(cell))

Any idea how can I mix these 2 conditions?

Comment: Remove the picklist from Source and place into cells. If they are placed on a helper sheet, be sure to qualify their range with the sheet reference. Data Validation List Source formula `=IF($J$6="",$J$6,$J$1:$J$5)` checks the blankness of $J$6 including `=""` or a formula that results in `""` (or truly blank cells). When `IF` is true, a blank cell is the only valid selection in the pick list. The List Source does not allow array constants so a range (even a single cell as a range) is used instead of what a normal formula would use `""` for blank. The cell referenced $J$6 can be any blank cell.

Comment: @TedD., that looks a lot like an answer.  :-)